# How to print .doc file using PrinteJob?

Tags: java

I want to print test3.doc file. I have tried this with java.awt.print.PrinterJob; Here is the code I have tried:

```
    PrinterJob printerjob= PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();        
    PageFormat pageformat=new PageFormat();
    Paper paper=new Paper();
    paper.setSize(8.27, 11.69);
    pageformat.setPaper(paper);
    printerjob.defaultPage(pageformat);
    text.setText(printerjob.getUserName());
    printerjob.pageDialog(pageformat);
    printerjob.printDialog();
    String file="C:/test3.doc";
    printerjob.setJobName(file);
    try{
    printerjob.print();
    text.setText("success");
    }
    catch (PrinterException e){text.setText("error");}
```

But it does not print any file.Does anyone have any idea why does not it work? Or how can I change code in order to print test3.doc file.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the Java API docs, `setJobName(String)` sets the name of the document to be printed, but this does not reference the document but instead it's just a name for the job, which can be anything like *"MyPrintJobName"*.

When printing a document, this document needs to be rendered and the resulting "graphics" is then sent to the printer as described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html

So, to print a .doc file from pure Java code, you need an engine which is able to render the document accordingly. Having a look at similar questions, there does not seem to be such an engine provided by Oracle with Java so you need to use a third-party component for handling .doc files.